# How to define index "UserName" in session?

Tags: php, html, session

I'm trying to show the login form to visitors only and hide it when user is logged in. I've seen similar question here but I couldn't get the answer. In the current code I get the Login form which is included from another page and also an error " Undefined index: UserName". So how can I define it?

```
<?php session_start() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="IndexStyle.css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width= device-width, intial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<body class="body">
    <header class="MainHeader">
    <img src="images/header-image-5.jpg">
    <nav><ul>
         <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="Product.php">Products</a></li>
         <li><a href="AboutUs.php">About Us</a></li>
         <li><a href="ContactUs.php">Contact Us</a></li>
         <div id="AdminP">
            <li><a href="AdminPanel.php">Admin Panel</a></li>
         </div>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <div class="MainBody">
        <p>This is Mainbody 
        </p>
    </div>
    <aside class="SideBar">
        <div class="login">
<?php
    if($_SESSION['UserName'] == "") {

        include 'Form.php';
    } else {
        echo "Logged in";
    }
?>
        </div>        
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </aside>
    <Footer class="Footer"> 
        <p>Copyrights reserved 
        </p>
    </Footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is the code that actually attempts to set the session variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check session right way `if($_SESSION['UserName'] == "") {`

You can use [isset](http://www.php.net/isset)  and [empty](http://www.php.net/empty) for checking session.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['UserName']) && !empty($_SESSION['UserName']))
{
include 'Form.php';
}
else {
echo "Logged in";
}
```

you can also use [array_key_exists](http://www.php.net/array_key_exists) instend of isset

```
session_start();
if(array_key_exists('UserName',$_SESSION) && !empty($_SESSION['UserName'])) {
include 'Form.php';
}else{
echo "Logged in";
}
```

Above methods for (especially for array keys) it works and also you can go for

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['UserName']) || $_SESSION['UserName'] == '')
```

Comment: All three show no errors. First two keep showing the echo and last one shows the form even after I login. Do I need to change anything in the form page?

Comment: @ItssMohammed you can remove else part if you don't want to show echo

Comment: Gianani I found the problem. I changed 'UserName' to 'MM_Username' and it worked. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this
Dear Change your php code

```
<?php
    if(!(isset($_SESSION['UserName']) && $_SESSION['UserName'] != "")) 
    {
      echo "Logged in";
    } 
    else 
    {
     include 'form.php';
    }
?>
```

Comment: I keep getting the form everytime even after I login. Is there any changes I should make to the Form.php page?

Comment: where to go after login @ItssMohammed

Comment: I put if login succeeded go to same page (index.php) and it was successful because I was able to go to Admin Panel page.

Comment: replace "Logged in" to your admin panel path @ItssMohammed

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['UserName']) &&  $_SESSION['UserName']== "") {

        include 'Form.php';
    } else {
        echo "Logged in";
    }
?>
```

hope this will help you

Comment: I think perhaps that should be `if(!isset($_SESSION['UserName']) or  $_SESSION['UserName']== "")` ~ or easier `if( empty($_SESSION['UserName']) )`?

Comment: @Amit Gaud It shows the echo at all time. Am I missing any php code in the beginning?

Comment: @RamRaider I tried `if( empty($_SESSION....` but it shows the form even after I log in.